# iOS: Application in production. Which Size?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I am developping my first application on iOS. I am on this language since few days and I am going to share this application in Apple Store ASAP. But I have a big question around architecture.

Currently, I have with about 40 different type of Views, others components and a lot of PNG (30x30). I know that I can reduce considerably the number of Views through the development of a small framework but as it's my first learning-by-practice application, I wanted to move on quickly about all standards components and to start this development without architecture, reusables class or design pattern ... without think too hard.

To be short, I am wondering about the real size of applications in production and the performances. Have we got some constraints with:

- Apple Store (upload apps)
- Ram Capacity of iPhone during using
- Download application from apple store for the user
  etc...

Basicly, is it acceptable to have with about 40 screens for an iPhone Application?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limit of 50 MB for over-the-air downloads.

Number of screens is probably not going to be a problem. The amount of executable code associated with each screen is probably not going to be significant. The bigger issue is how much PNG data you are going to have embedded in the app. A single 30x30 PNG isn't very big. 40 of them probably won't very big (depending on how well they compress). But if you have dozens of them per screen, or if you have a big hi-res background image for each screen, then the total amount of data could get big.

My advice would be to just start developing everything in the most straightforward way you can. Don't worry about sizes until you have some evidence that it may be a problem. And do a lot of testing on an actual device (don't rely on the Simulator) running whatever the oldest OS version is that you are willing to support.

Comment: Hmmm ... I forgot ... I also have several MP3 :( ... In anyway, I will follow your advice and will see if the problems comes . 
Thx your very much Kristopher.